# D3 Chart print issue

Tags: css, d3.js, printing, charts

I have a page with d3 charts in it.
If I try to take print of the page, it crops the chart in half.

But if I set the max width of page to 700 px , then it shows good in print emulation in chrome browser. But again it crops the charts in print preview.

So should I convert the charts to images for printing? How do people work with d3 for printing?

Comment: Can you host your d3 chart somewhere? A quick way would be on Github's gist, then we can see it bl.ocks.org/<your_git_username>/raw/. I'm personally not having this issue with my charts.

Comment: If i reduce the width of page, the charts are less cropped. So while printing, should I diable animations or transitions ? I had tried it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be in you have used some external css ... when we use external css with SVG elements it will miss them on time of printing because , SVG in print not able to get that css .. so you check this, that all css that you need build SVG that is available in SVG's  tag as inline css ..

and for check you can copy that entire SVG element and save that in new file as .SVG extension and see how it give you results .. If it gives you same result as you pie than check with print ...